# How can I add control character in QR in Python QRcode module

Tags: python, tkinter, qr-code

I've tried to add control character (e.g. tab, enter etc) between text in python QRcode module.
I can't find reference or introduction how can I add it.
Could you please advise it?

I just make code simply like below.

```
from tkinter import *
import qrcode

root = Tk()

root.title('My QRcode Generator') #window title
root.geometry("640x480+300+100") #width X hegith + x + Y

e = Entry(root, width=30)
e.pack()

label1 = Label(root, text='QRIMAGE')
label1.pack()

def btncmd():
    img = qrcode.make(e.get())
    a = e.get()
    img.save( a + '.png')
    global photo
    photo = PhotoImage(file=a+'.png')
    label1.config(image=photo)

btn1= Button(root, text='generate QRcode', command = btncmd)
btn1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried creating the qr code with the text from a hard-coded string, to see if the problem is with the qr code library or with pulling data out of the entry widget?

Comment: Do you mean to make code like this? ```qrcode.make('AAAA' + chr(9) + '1234566')```

Comment: Yes. If that works, then the problem is between tkinter and the calling of the function. If it doesn't work, then there's nothing tkinter can do to fix it since the problem is inside the function.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment. This hard-coded string works correctly. I need to find how can I make code working in entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An entry widget only accepts a single line of text. It's possible to insert a newline, but you won't be able to see it. If you want to be able to see it, you'll have to use a `Text` widget.

The default behavior of a tab is to move the focus to the next widget so that the user can navigate the UI from the keyboard.

If you want the user to be able insert a tab or newline into the entry widget, you'll have to add special bindings that insert the string and then prevent the default action.

For example:

```
def insert_special(char):
    e.insert("insert", char)
    return "break"

entry.bind("<Tab>", lambda event: insert_special("\t"))
entry.bind("<Return>", lambda event: insert_special("\n"))
```

Note: if you use the `Text` widget you won't have to do the binding since it allows tabs and newlines.